# php7.0-fpm emergency_restart_threshold option

Tags: php-fpm

I'm setting up `nginx` and `php7.0-fpm` on `Ubuntu 16.0.4`. I haven't used `nginx` and `php7.0-fpm` combo before so I was following a number of guides. The guides I found all recommended adding the following config option to the `www.conf` file for `php7.0-fpm`

```
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 20s
```

(the values are just placeholders for the time being)

The problem is when I try to restart `php7.0-fpm` after adding those options it's fails to start with the following error implying that those options are no longer valid.

```
ERROR: [/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:414] unknown entry 'emergency_restart_threshold'
```

Do these options still exist in some form and if so what have they changed to? If they don't what is the alternative to make `php7.0-fpm` automatically restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like these options need to be set in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf` rather than `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` as some sources cited.

Comment: You can set them in `pool.d` also but must define `[global]` section before that. Without section FPM won't start. *Tested on php7.1-fpm ubuntu (server 18).*